# Is there a way to call an external html code into a yaml file

Tags: html, yaml, openapi

I am creating a documentation with Redoc in Springboot and i am looking to call sections from html files instead of writing everything in a yaml file

this is the exemple in the yaml file :

```
tags:
- name: Description
description: |
<p>This is the <strong>Description</strong>of the API.</p>
```

is there a way to call the paragraph from a html file since sometime it could be long paragraphs and perhabes i could use some design with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using `externalDocs` property.

This property allows you to define a url where documentation is hosted for the api.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: my api
  version: 1.0.0
externalDocs:
  description: a link to my external documentation for this api
  url: https://developer.myapi.com
servers: []
paths: {}
components: {}
```

---

Alternatively, you can reference external markdown documents using `$ref` for descriptions. This can be a nice way to externalize and manage all of your descriptions. This method can be used for any `description` property throughout the OpenAPI description document.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: my api
  version: 1.0.0
servers: []
paths: {}
components:
  schemas:
    my_schema:
      description:
        $ref: './docs/my_schema_docs.md
```

###### docs/my_schema_docs.md

```
some text about my api using CommonMark syntax described by OpenAPI
```

*src: [CommonMark syntax](https://learn.openapis.org/specification/docs.html#the-commonmark-syntax)*